$n$ linear equations for $n+1$ unknowns
Let us consider a linear system
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_{11}x_1 + \dots + a_{1n}x_n + b_1y &=& c_1 \\
&\dots&\\
a_{n1}x_1 + \dots + a_{nn}x_n + b_ny &=& c_n
\end{eqnarray*}
for unknowns $x_1,\dots,x_n,y$. Is there a simple criterion to decide if there is a unique solution for the unknown $y$ or if there are infinitely many solutions or no solutions for $y$?

O.p. specified in the comments that we may as well assume that ranks of all relevant matrices are known, and we can give a simple criterion in terms of matrix ranks. Now, the Rouché-Capelli Theorem says that a vector $\bf z \in \Bbb F^n$ is in the image of a matrix $P \in \Bbb F^{n \times m}$ if and only if $$\operatorname{rank} \pmatrix{P \mid {\bf z}} = \operatorname{rank} P .$$
Our system is
$$\pmatrix{{\bf A} & {\bf b}} \pmatrix{{\bf x}\\ y} = {\bf c} .$$
Suppose there is a solution for more than $1$ $y$-value, say, $({\bf x}_0, y_0)$ and $({\bf x}_1, y_1)$ are both solutions, where $y_0 \neq y_1$. Then, $A \left(-\frac{{\bf x}_1 - {\bf x}_0}{y_1 - y_0}\right) = {\bf b}$, hence ${\bf b} \in \operatorname{im} A$, and the converse also holds. We also get solutions for all values of $y \in \Bbb F$.
So:

There are no solutions iff
$$\operatorname{rank} \pmatrix{{\bf A} & {\bf b} & {\bf c}} > \operatorname{rank} \pmatrix{{\bf A} & {\bf b}} .$$
There is a solution for exactly $1$ value $y \in \Bbb F$ iff
$$\operatorname{rank} \pmatrix{{\bf A} & {\bf b} & {\bf c}} = \operatorname{rank} \pmatrix{{\bf A} & {\bf b}} > \operatorname{rank} {\bf A}$$
There are solutions for all $y \in \Bbb F$ iff
$$\operatorname{rank} \pmatrix{{\bf A} & {\bf b} & {\bf c}} = \operatorname{rank} \pmatrix{{\bf A} & {\bf b}} = \operatorname{rank} {\bf A}.$$
The last condition is equivalent to the single equality $\operatorname{rank} \pmatrix{{\bf A} & {\bf b} & {\bf c}} = \operatorname{rank} {\bf A}$.

If $\operatorname{rank} {\bf A} = n$ (i.e., if $\bf A$ is nonsingular), then there are solutions for all $\lambda$.

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
You can write your equations in vector form as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\mathbf{a}_i+y\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{c}\ ,\tag{1}\label{e1}
$$
where
\begin{align}
\mathbf{a}_i&\ed\pmatrix{a_{1i}&a_{2i}&\dots&a_{ni}}\\
\mathbf{b}&\ed\pmatrix{b_1&b_2&\dots&b_n}\ \ \ \text{and}\\
\mathbf{c}&\ed\pmatrix{c_1&c_2&\dots&c_n}\ .
\end{align}
The space of vectors with $\ n\ $ components in a field has dimension $\ n\ .$ One of the fundamental facts of linear algebra, which follows from the Steinitz replacement lemma, is that any multiset of more than $\ n\ $ vectors in a vector space of dinension $\ n\ $ must be linearly dependent. This is true of the multiset $\ \big\{\mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{a}_2,\dots,\mathbf{a}_n,\mathbf{b}\big\}\ ,$ which means there exists a set of scalars $\ \big\{\xi_1,\xi_2,\dots,\xi_{n+1}\big\}\ ,$ not all zero, such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_i\mathbf{a}_i+\xi_{n+1}\mathbf{b}=\pmatrix{0&0&\dots&0}\tag{2}\label{e2}\ .
$$
Thus, if $\ x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n, y\ $ constitute a solution of equation (\ref{e1}) then so do  $\ x_1+t\xi_1,x_2+t\xi_2,\dots, x_n+t\xi_n, y+t\xi_{n+1}\ $ for any scalar $\ t\ .$ Thus, $\ y\ $ can be unique in a solution to equation (\ref{e1}) only if every solution of equation (\ref{e2}) has $\ \xi_{n+1}=0\ .$ This will be true if and only if the vector $\ \mathbf{b}\ $ is not in the space spanned by the multiset $\ \big\{\mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{a}_2,\dots,\mathbf{a}_n\big\}\ $ (which implies that this multiset would already have to be linearly dependent). Conversely, if $\ x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n, y\ $ constitute a solution of equation (\ref{e1}),  $\ \mathbf{b}\ $ is not in the space spanned by the multiset $\ \big\{\mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{a}_2,\dots,\mathbf{a}_n\big\}\ $ and $\ \mathbf{c}_1\ $ is the perpendicular projection of $\ \mathbf{c}\ $ onto that space (which is unique), then $\ \mathbf{c}-\mathbf{c}_1\ $ is perpendicular to the space, $\ (\mathbf{c}-\mathbf{c}_1)\cdot\mathbf{b}\ne0\ $ and $\ y=\frac{\|\mathbf{c}-\mathbf{c}_1\|^2}{(\mathbf{c}-\mathbf{c}_1)\cdot\mathbf{b}}\ $ is uniquely determined.
On the other hand, a solution to equation (\ref{e1}) exists if and only if $\ \mathbf{c}\ $ lies in the space spanned by $\ \big\{\mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{a}_2,\dots,\mathbf{a}_n,\mathbf{b}\big\}\ .$
To summarise:

Equation (\ref{e1}) has a solution which is unique for $\ y\ $ if and only if $\ \mathbf{c}\ $ lies in the space spanned by $\ \big\{\mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{a}_2,\dots,\mathbf{a}_n,\mathbf{b}\big\}\ $ and  $\ \mathbf{b}\ $ is not in the space spanned by  $\ \big\{\mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{a}_2,\dots,\mathbf{a}_n\big\}\ .$
Equation (\ref{e1}) has a solution with an infinite number of values for $\ y\ $ if and only if both $\ \mathbf{c}\ $  and  $\ \mathbf{b}\ $ lie in the space spanned by  $\ \big\{\mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{a}_2,\dots,\mathbf{a}_n\big\}\ .$
Equation (\ref{e1}) has no solution if and only if $\ \mathbf{c}\ $ does not lie in the space spanned by $\ \big\{\mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{a}_2,\dots,\mathbf{a}_n,\mathbf{b}\big\}\ .$

As noted in Travis White's answer, these criteria can be restated in terms of the ranks $\ r_1,r_2,r_3\ $ of the matrices
\begin{align}
&\left[\matrix{\mathbf{a}_1^T&\mathbf{a}_2^T&\dots&\mathbf{a}_n^T}\right]\ ,\\
&\left[\matrix{\mathbf{a}_1^T&\mathbf{a}_2^T&\dots&\mathbf{a}_n^T&\mathbf{b}^T}\right]\ \ \text{ and}\\
&\left[\matrix{\mathbf{a}_1^T&\mathbf{a}_2^T&\dots&\mathbf{a}_n^T&\mathbf{b}^T&\mathbf{c}^T}\right]
\end{align}
respectively, which must satisfy the inequalities $\ r_1\le$$\,r_2\le$$\,r_3\ :$

Equation (\ref{e1}) has a solution which is unique for $\ y\ $ if and only if  $\ r_1<$$\,r_2=$$\,r_3\ .$
Equation (\ref{e1}) has a solution with an infinite number of values for $\ y\ $ if and only if $\ r_1=$$\,r_2=$$\,r_3\ .$
Equation (\ref{e1}) has no solution if and only if $\ r_2< r_3\ .$

